# Suspicious activity through postfix/smtpd in mail.info - maybe virus or hacking attempt?

Tags: server, email, postfix

I found the following entries in mail.info but nobody is logged in.
Clamscan find nothing. How can i find what this is and how can i stop this?

> Oct 26 11:30:03 smtp postfix/smtpd[21749]: connect from
>   localhost[127.0.0.1]
>
> Oct 26 11:30:03 smtp postfix/smtpd[21749]: warning: valid_hostname:
>   numeric hostname: 95.140.39.1010 Oct 26 11:30:03 smtp
>   postfix/smtpd[21749]: warning: malformed domain name in resource data
>   of MX record for phpwzym.com: 95.140.39.1010
>
> Oct 26 11:30:03 smtp postfix/smtpd[21749]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from
>   localhost[127.0.0.1]: 450 4.1.8 :
>   Sender address rejected: Malformed DNS server reply;
>   from= to=
>   proto=ESMTP helo=
>
> Oct 26 11:30:03 smtp postfix/smtpd[21749]: disconnect from
>   localhost[127.0.0.1]

Thanks Michl

Answer (score 1):

Attacker come from

```
xxx@yyy ~ $ host phpwzym.com
phpwzym.com has address 95.140.38.3
phpwzym.com mail is handled by 10 95.140.39.1010.

xxx@yyy ~ $ whois 95.140.38.3
% This is the RIPE Database query service.
% The objects are in RPSL format.
%
% The RIPE Database is subject to Terms and Conditions.
% See http://www.ripe.net/db/support/db-terms-conditions.pdf

% Note: this output has been filtered.
%       To receive output for a database update, use the "-B" flag.

% Information related to '95.140.38.0 - 95.140.38.255'

% Abuse contact for '95.140.38.0 - 95.140.38.255' is 'abuse@szervernet.hu'

inetnum:        95.140.38.0 - 95.140.38.255
netname:        TERATRADE-NET
descr:          VPS SERVERS
country:        HU
admin-c:        TK6395-RIPE
tech-c:         TK6395-RIPE
status:         ASSIGNED PA
mnt-by:         KGY-MNT
mnt-by:         TK6395-MNT
mnt-routes:     TK6395-MNT
created:        2015-03-10T11:12:04Z
last-modified:  2015-05-21T19:34:36Z
source:         RIPE # Filtered

role:           Teratrade Kft
address:        Hungary
address:        1123 Budapest
address:        Nagyt�t�nyi �t 190.
phone:          +36303654560
abuse-mailbox:  abuse@edm-campaigns.com
nic-hdl:        TK6395-RIPE
mnt-by:         TK6395-MNT
created:        2015-03-12T16:01:42Z
last-modified:  2015-03-17T14:48:56Z
source:         RIPE # Filtered
```

`Teratrade` also allow creation of fake dns records

```
phpwzym.com mail is handled by 10 95.140.39.1010.
```

With your firewall you can block access from this `host` or from this `network`

```
UFW

sudo ufw enable

# for host
sudo ufw deny from 95.140.39.xxx

# for network
sudo ufw deny from 95.140.39.xxx/24

# allow all other to connect on port 25 aka smtp port
sudo ufw allow 25

# allow other port's 
sudo ufw allow 110 # pop3 port
sudo ufw allow xxx # for xxx port
```

You do not see now any connection because mail are in queue and wait for delivery.

Command to empty queue in postfix is

```
sudo postsuper -d ALL
```